# testing using google test multithreading

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost-asio, googletest

I need to tests multithreading code using google tests.
Is any method to stop/block google test thread execution (I mean in the same test) until an event is happening? And after that event happens to go further with the test execution.

Thank you

Comment: `std::condition_variable` in your testing code perhaps